# Try to track down Blazor Client side Exception

Tags: exception, blazor-webassembly

We have been using RadzenBlazor for a while now with good success. Recently, the Filtering is causing an exception. The actual exception is not forthcoming to me so I am wondering how to better read it. I know Blazor client side errors are not so great. Most of the time, when it is code I have written you get a variable or something to point me in the direction of the cause, but not in this case as near as I can tell. I can select items and unselect items with no issue. The second I type in a letter to filter down the list, I get the exception below. I am just trying to figure out if it is Radzen or something else.

I have tried implementing [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly#alternative-global-exception-handling) from the Microsoft Docs but no extra info was shown.

First, here is the code, for the DropDown

```
<RadzenDropDown Multiple="true"
                AllowClear="true"
                AllowFiltering="true"
                FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
                Placeholder="Select Claim(s)..."
                @bind-Value="SelectedClaimIds"
                Data="availablePerformanceClaims"
                TextProperty="Name"
                ValueProperty="Id"
                TValue="IEnumerable<int>"
                Class="w-100 items-inline">
</RadzenDropDown>

[Inject]
private ISomeService someService { get; set; }

[Inject]
private IMapper mapper { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<PerformanceClaimMinimalModel> availablePerformanceClaims { get; set; } = new List<PerformanceClaimMinimalModel>();
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedClaimIds = Array.Empty<int>();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  availablePerformanceClaims = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SelectablePerformanceClaimMinimalModel>>(
    await someService .GetPerformanceClaimsAsync(new PerformanceClaimSearchModel
    {
      ValidUntilEnd = null,
    })
  )
  .OrderBy(x => x.Issuer)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Version);
}
```

And here is the exception

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.KeywordsHelper..ctor(ParsingConfig config)
at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser..ctor(ParameterExpression[] parameters, String expression, Object[] values, ParsingConfig parsingConfig)
at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(Type delegateType, ParsingConfig parsingConfig, Boolean createParameterCtor, ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(ParsingConfig parsingConfig, Boolean createParameterCtor, ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(ParsingConfig parsingConfig, Boolean createParameterCtor, Type itType, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions.Where(IQueryable source, ParsingConfig config, String predicate, Object[] args)
at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions.Where(IQueryable source, String predicate, Object[] args)
at Radzen.DropDownBase`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].get_View()
at Radzen.Blazor.RadzenDropDown`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
window.Module.s.printErr  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
Te._internal.dotNetCriticalError  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
Rt  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
$func219  @  00970c26:0x1a0fb
$func167  @  00970c26:0xcac9
$func166  @  00970c26:0xb9dc
$func2810  @  00970c26:0xabb22
$func1615  @  00970c26:0x6f935
$func1619  @  00970c26:0x6ffa2
$mono_wasm_invoke_method  @  00970c26:0x969b
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS  @  managed__Microsoft_A…time_EndInvokeJS:16
endInvokeJSFromDotNet  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous)  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
Promise.then (async)    
beginInvokeJSFromDotNet  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
Rt  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
$func219  @  00970c26:0x1a0fb
$func167  @  00970c26:0xcac9
$func166  @  00970c26:0xb9dc
$func2810  @  00970c26:0xabb22
$func1615  @  00970c26:0x6f935
$func1619  @  00970c26:0x6ffa2
$func3213  @  00970c26:0xc4abd
$mono_background_exec  @  00970c26:0x93f6d
Module._mono_background_exec  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
pump_message  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
setTimeout (async)    
_schedule_background_exec  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
$func2387  @  00970c26:0x93f1e
$func3212  @  00970c26:0xc4a4d
$func219  @  00970c26:0x1a163
$func167  @  00970c26:0xcac9
$func166  @  00970c26:0xb9dc
$func2810  @  00970c26:0xabb22
$func1615  @  00970c26:0x6f935
$func1619  @  00970c26:0x6ffa2
$mono_set_timeout_exec  @  00970c26:0xc49ba
Module._mono_set_timeout_exec  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
mono_wasm_set_timeout_exec  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
mono_wasm_set_timeout_exec  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
setTimeout (async)    
_mono_set_timeout  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
$func3211  @  00970c26:0xc4a45
$func219  @  00970c26:0x1a030
$func167  @  00970c26:0xcac9
$func166  @  00970c26:0xb9dc
$func2810  @  00970c26:0xabb22
$func1615  @  00970c26:0x6f935
$func1613  @  00970c26:0x6f8a7
$func966  @  00970c26:0x502f8
$func219  @  00970c26:0x1a0b4
$func167  @  00970c26:0xcac9
$func166  @  00970c26:0xb9dc
$func2810  @  00970c26:0xabb22
$func1615  @  00970c26:0x6f935
$func1613  @  00970c26:0x6f8a7
$func966  @  00970c26:0x502f8
$func219  @  00970c26:0x1a0b4
$func167  @  00970c26:0xcac9
$func166  @  00970c26:0xb9dc
$func2810  @  00970c26:0xabb22
$func1615  @  00970c26:0x6f935
$func1619  @  00970c26:0x6ffa2
$mono_wasm_invoke_method  @  00970c26:0x969b
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method  @  dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1
managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_BeginInvokeDotNet  @  managed__Microsoft_A…eginInvokeDotNet:19
beginInvokeDotNetFromJS  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
b  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
invokeMethodAsync  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous)  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
invokeWhenHeapUnlocked  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
S  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
C  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
dispatchGlobalEventToAllElements  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
onGlobalEvent  @  blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

Comment: Am not familiar with Radzen, but you can see the call stack shows that the error happens deeper than methods in the RadzenDropDown, so it would appear the error is uncaught inside the Radzen component.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was [BlazorApplicationInsights](https://github.com/ivanjosipovic/blazorapplicationinsights) that was giving me an issue. I may be doing it wrong, but we have an HttpService and I was trying to catch errors, which it does. But clearly Radzen has issues with it. I have no issues with the BAI, but I will have to circle back on figure out what the  issue is.

```
private async Task<bool> HandleResponseFailure(HttpVerbs verb, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
{
  if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    await appInsights.TrackException(
      new Error
      {
        Message = responseMessage.ReasonPhrase,
        Name = $"{verb.ToString().ToUpper()} Request Exception: StatusCode: {responseMessage.StatusCode} - {responseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri}",
      }
    );
    Utils.HideSpinner();
    Utils.WriteError(jsRuntime, $"Error during {verb.ToString().ToUpper()}, Status Code: {responseMessage.StatusCode}, Uri: {responseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri}");
    // TODO: Do we want this -> Utils.ShowErrorNotification($"{verb.ToString().ToUpper()} Exception", $"Status Code: {responseMessage.StatusCode}\n{responseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri}");
  }

  return responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```